# Run CURL script after build job jenkins

Tags: http, curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to trigger a CURL command after the build job in the post build state in Jenkins

is there any plugin or a  way to invoke the CURL script

Answer (score 2):

here's a full Jenkinsfile that does that:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('build') {
      steps {
        echo "build"
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        sh "curl -v 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```